# Sync a single Google Calendar with CalDav

Tags: thunderbird, google-calendar, lightning, caldav

At work we use Mozilla Thunderbird with Lightning plugin to manage our calendar, and I want to sync with my Google Calendar account.

The problem is that in my Google Calendar account, I have 3 specific calendars, and I just want to sync one of them.

If I use the XML option in Lighting I can't accept any invite.

I tried the iCal mode, but it didn't worked.

So I tried to use the CalDav and it worked, but it syncs all 3 of my calendars.

The [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/caldav/v2/guide) suggests to use this link to connect the CalDav:

```
https://apidata.googleusercontent.com/caldav/v2/yourID/events
```

I want to sync just a single calendar of my Google Calendar Account with the Lighting plugin in Thunderbird.

Can I have some CalDav url to set just a specific calendar instead of all 3 calendars?

Thuderbird 24.5
Lightning 2.6.5

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use the URL you suggest, `https://apidata.googleusercontent.com/caldav/v2/yourID/events`, but rather than using `your.cool.username@gmail.com` as the substitute for `yourID`, put in the calendar name instead.

To find that name, start with a Google Calendar window, then go to Settings->Calendars and click on the name of the Calendar you care about. Now scroll down to the "Calendar Address" row and look to the right of the XML/ICAL/HTML links to where it says "Calendar ID". This should look like an email address with a bunch of random-looking letters and numbers followed by `@group.calendar.google.com`. That whole thing is what you substitute for `yourID`.

Comment: Correct answer, but I'd like to add that using your.cool.username@gmail.com as the substitute for yourID gives you access to your primary calendar through CalDAV. It doesn't sync all of your calendars at once as the OP seems to suggest.

Comment: What authentication should be used for a Google calendar caldav? Just the user's regular login email & password?

Comment: Worth to mention the public WebCal subscription link for single calendars: `https://calendar.google.com/calendar/ical/yourID/public/basic.ics`

Comment: This method seems to no longer be working for newly created calendars. I get stuck in when I press the button to Find Calendars. Edit: this worked for me https://superuser.com/questions/1738934/cannot-add-caldav-google-calendar-to-thunderbird-anymore/1749331

Answer (score 1):

Try GDATA provider. It let's you sync a specific calendar from your google account.
https://wiki.mozilla.org/Calendar:GDATA_Provider#Accessing_your_Calendar

Comment: This GDATA is actuallly the Provider for Google Calendar 0.25. This tool work with just one calendar. But I cannot accept invite from Thunderbird and its not two-way.

Answer (score 0):

For DAVx⁵, use this:

https://forums.bitfire.at/topic/1966/davx5-is-adding-google-contacts-calendar-together

The CalDAV URL is:

https://www.google.com/calendar/dav/yourID/events