# Cannot add CalDAV google calendar to Thunderbird anymore

Tags: thunderbird, calendar, google-calendar, caldav

Previously, I've used the CalDAV api to add my personal google calendar to thunderbird.  Pretty straight forward.  Set the calendar location to

```
https://apidata.googleusercontent.com/caldav/v2/calid/events
```

replace `calid` with the appropriate calendar ID (your gmail address in most cases), and then an OAuth window pops up asking to log into your google account.  Done.

For the past 2 days, I've been trying to add my calendar to thunderbird 91.11, but it always just hangs on *"please wait while your calendars are being discovered"*, and I never make it to the OAuth step.

Can anyone verify that this process indeed still works on thunderbird?  I'm not sure what I could possibly be doing wrong here.

Comment: You should be getting a password prompt. Ensure that it didn't go behind Thunderbird. BTW, there are lots of complaints about this issue since Thunderbird 91.

Comment: hmm.. nope, definitely not hidden behind the client.  Are you aware of a ticket for this issue already?   Would be nice to check if anyone has posted a workaround there.

Comment: My URL ends in `/events` instead of `/user`.

Comment: @JoeEifert Thanx for catching that.  That was a typo in the question.  When I try this, I do indeed use `/events` at the end, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm honestly having problems since around a week with this. Worked fine for a few months up to now. That's why I came across this question. `The calendar X is momentarily not available`. Still seeing the events after I manually enable it every couple of hours.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update:

CalDAV still works with Thunderbird. You need to set up an app password as per here:
https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en

Then add a different API endpoint:
[https://www.google.com/calendar/dav/[CalID]/events](https://www.google.com/calendar/dav/%5BCalID%5D/events)

- CalID = [mailbox]@[domain] # formerly I used '%40' rather than '@', this is no longer necessary

Note. it's different to Google's own article:
https://developers.google.com/calendar/caldav/v2/guide#connecting_to_googles_caldav_server

Source:
https://www.davx5.com/tested-with/google

- Incidently DAVx5 is a great way to get a Google Calendar on Android without bolting an account into the OS. Such as if you don't want your work account to intrude on a personal device.

CalDAV still seems better than the 'Provider for Google Calendar' at handling email scheduling. I have experienced an issue where accepting a meeting invite creates a separate instance of the meeting with myself as the owner and notifies attendees of the new meeting (as alluded to in its options screen).

Comment: Fantastic!  Works for me.  Thanks for digging on this!

Comment: I had to also enter my gmail address in the `Username` field.  With the previous OAuth method, I think this step was unnecessary.

Comment: I'm trying this method, and while it seems to successfully find and add the calendar, I don't see any events, and adding events seems to fail silently. Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like my issue had something to do with Thunderbird. I re-added the calendar a couple times and toggled so I could view only the new calendar and now it is showing up.

Answer (score 1):

Same `The calendar X is momentarily not available` problem here with Thunderbird 102.2.2 on Ubuntu 20.04. In addition, on Tools > Developer Tools > Error Console, there is an error message from `calendar-invitations-manager.js:125` saying `Exception { name: "NS_ERROR_FAILURE", message: "CalDAV: Error: got status 403 fetching calendar data for <my-calid>, null", result: 2147500037, filename: "resource:///modules/CalDavCalendar.jsm", lineNumber: 1116, columnNumber: 0, data: null, stack: "notifyGetFailed@resource:///modules/CalDavCalendar.jsm:1116:41\nonStartRequest@resource:///modules/caldav/CalDavRequestHandlers.jsm:846:21\nonStartRequest@resource:///modules/caldav/CalDavRequest.jsm:544:48\n", location: XPCWrappedNative_NoHelper }`

The 403 error code sounds like authentication didn't work out.

Answer (score 0):

I am also seeing this issue when adding my work Gmail calendar to Thunderbird Lightning via CalDAV (102.3.1).

The calendar can be added normally following an oauth/2fa prompt, then I get 'calendar X is momentarily not available'. It does not load after a wait / sync. Removing passwords from tools > privacy > passwords, then re-adding the calendars does not resolve the issue. It does seem like a change has be recently made because it has worked well for a long time. However I can't find anything in the API release notes.

I've gone back to using 'Provider for Google Calendar' and adding calendars via that. So far so good, though originally I'd switched to CalDAV because it seemed to handle meeting invites better.

I have many calendars added Thunderbird, so I also have this set to true: calendar.network.multirealm. Though I don't think this effects 'Provider for Google Calendar'.